# Reading a File with Different Data Types Into Tree

Tags: java, file-io

I have an object `Movie` which contains these data members: title(string), year(int), and list of actors(ArrayList). I want to read from the file and create a new Movie object with the information from the file. This is an example text from the file:

```
Star Wars/1977/Mark Hamill,Carrie Fisher,Harrison Ford
```

How would I add the file to the tree to meet the conditions of my Constructor:

```
public class Movie {
private String title;
private int year;
private ArrayList<String> actors;

public Movie( String t, int y, ArrayList<String> a ){
    title = t;
    year = y;
    actors = a;
}
```

How I am trying to add File (I know it would work if everything was of type String):

```
try{
        Scanner read = new Scanner( new File("movies.txt") );
        do{
            String line = read.nextLine();
            String [] tokens = line.split("/");
            //How would I change this to allow for differnt data types.
            tree.add( new Movie(tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2] );
        }while( read.hasNext() );
        read.close();
    }catch( FileNotFoundException fnf){
        System.out.println("File not found.");
    }
```

I am thinking I would need to create my `ArrayList` here as well as an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the type.
1) convert the tokens[1] into integer by using `Integer.parseIt(tokens[1]);`

2) for array list again spilt the tokens[2] by "," and add it to an arraylist. Use `arraylist.add()` for adding the values in the arraylist.

3) call the constructor using string int and arraylist variables.

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is not clear, but any way you can add this if I correctly understand you

```
 tree.add( new Movie(tokens[0], Integer. Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]),Arrays.asList(tokens[2].split(",") );
```